# Integromat Iterator - Bundles Versus Operations?

Tags: make.com

In Integromat, I am updating a Trello dropdown by iterating an array of Google Contact names. I am successfully seeing multiple Bundles in the Output I am NOT getting multiple runs of the Trello "Make and API Call" module.

Perhaps I need multiple Operations rather than multiple Bundles?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out I was setup correctly...

BUT

I had another Trello API call I was trying to make after iterating all the bundles.

That subsequent API call seems to have haltted the bundle iteration due to an error.